# command not found: webpack in yarn Berry monorepo

Tags: monorepo, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v3

Working on a yarn 3.6.x monorepo with multiple workspaces spread over 2 different folders i do get an error when invoking scripts in the workspaces. I do not have this issue locally, also not when checking the repository out from scratch. Though other team members and in our build pipeline i do face this issue.

The workspaces can be divided in local config packages and apps. App workspaces have (dev)Dependencies to the local config workspaces. Simplified the repo structure resembles:

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── cancel
│       ├── .eslintrc.js
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       └── webpack.config.js
│   └── leisure
│       ├── .eslintrc.js
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       └── webpack.config.js
├── configs
│   ├── eslint
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── webpack
│       ├── config
│       └── package.json
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

The package.json at the root level of the project is;

```
{
  "name": "@myorg/monorepo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Products",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "all:build": "yarn workspaces foreach --include @anwb/account-products-cancel --include @anwb/account-products-leisure --parallel run build",
    "all:lint": "yarn workspaces foreach --verbose --parallel run lint",
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/cancel",
    "apps/leisure",
    "configs/eslint",
    "configs/webpack"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
 ...
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.0",
  "team": "Mijn Org",
  "title": "Monorepo setup"
}
```

The app `package.json` scripts are similar to:

```
{
    "name": "@anwb/account-products-leisure",
    "sideEffects": false,
    "version": "1.5.0",
    "private": true,
    "description": "Account Products Leisure",
    "license": "ISC",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --mode=production",
        "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.tsx src",
    },
    "dependencies": {
...
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@anwb/style-utilities": "^4.10.0",
        "@anwb/test-utils": "^3.0.1",
        "prettier": "2.6.2",
        "puppeteer": "^13.1.3",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "react-select-event": "^5.5.1",
        "sonarqube-scanner": "2.8.1",
        "standard-version": "9.3.2",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.8.0"
    },
    "team": "Mijn Org",
    "title": "Products Cancel"
}
```

When running locally `yarn all:build` or `yarn all:lint` the scripts complete successful. But when executed on other systems or in Gitlab i do get the error;

```
$ yarn all:lint
[@myorg/products-cancel]: Process started
[@myorg/products-leisure]: Process started
[@myorg/products-cancel]: command not found: eslint
[@myorg/products-cancel]: Process exited (exit code 127), completed in 0s 759ms
[@myorg/products-leisure]: command not found: eslint
[@myorg/products-leisure]: Process exited (exit code 127), completed in 0s 743ms
Done in 0s 762ms
```

Same issue when building the workspaces, where webpack is not found. Webpack and eslint are in the root node_modules folder

*update 1*
Found the cause, locally i am used to run yarn in the integrated terminal session of my IDE. In this terminal session the `monorepo/node_modules/.bin` is added to the path. When running in a separate terminal (macOS) or gitlab pipeline, the location of `node_modules/.bin` is not added to path.